# how to use column values in window function range between

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I have a pyspark dataframe which looks like this (formatted for better view, data partitioned by `company_id` and `as_on_date` ordering by `t_tax_period`)

```
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|company_master_id|as_on_date|t_tax_period|delay_days|days_90_before|days_180_before|days_365_before|
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|                3|2022-08-01|  2022-06-30|        10|    2022-05-03|     2022-02-02|     2021-08-01|
|                3|2022-08-01|  2022-03-31|        12|    2022-05-03|     2022-02-02|     2021-08-01|
|                3|2022-08-01|  2021-12-31|        18|    2022-05-03|     2022-02-02|     2021-08-01|
|                3|2022-08-01|  2021-09-30|         6|    2022-05-03|     2022-02-02|     2021-08-01|
|                3|2022-08-01|  2021-06-30|         5|    2022-05-03|     2022-02-02|     2021-08-01|
|-----------------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
|                3|2022-08-02|  2022-06-30|        11|    2022-05-04|     2022-02-03|     2021-08-02|
|                3|2022-08-02|  2022-03-31|        12|    2022-05-04|     2022-02-03|     2021-08-02|
|                3|2022-08-02|  2021-12-31|        18|    2022-05-04|     2022-02-03|     2021-08-02|
|                3|2022-08-02|  2021-09-30|         6|    2022-05-04|     2022-02-03|     2021-08-02|
|                3|2022-08-02|  2021-06-30|         5|    2022-05-04|     2022-02-03|     2021-08-02|
|-----------------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
|                3|2022-08-03|  2022-06-30|        12|    2022-05-05|     2022-02-04|     2021-08-03|
|                3|2022-08-03|  2022-03-31|        12|    2022-05-05|     2022-02-04|     2021-08-03|
|                3|2022-08-03|  2021-12-31|        18|    2022-05-05|     2022-02-04|     2021-08-03|
|                3|2022-08-03|  2021-09-30|         6|    2022-05-05|     2022-02-04|     2021-08-03|
|                3|2022-08-03|  2021-06-30|         5|    2022-05-05|     2022-02-04|     2021-08-03|
|-----------------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
|                3|2022-08-04|  2022-06-30|        13|    2022-05-06|     2022-02-05|     2021-08-04|
|                3|2022-08-04|  2022-03-31|        12|    2022-05-06|     2022-02-05|     2021-08-04|
|                3|2022-08-04|  2021-12-31|        18|    2022-05-06|     2022-02-05|     2021-08-04|
|                3|2022-08-04|  2021-09-30|         6|    2022-05-06|     2022-02-05|     2021-08-04|
|                3|2022-08-04|  2021-06-30|         5|    2022-05-06|     2022-02-05|     2021-08-04|
|-----------------|----------|------------|----------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
```

`days_90_before` = `as_on_date`  - 90 days

`days_180_before` = `as_on_date` - 180 days

`days_365_before` = `as_on_date` - 365 days

Now i want to calculate `max(delay_days)` for the last 90, 180, 365 days before `as_on_date`. This is by checking the `t_tax_period` falls between as_on_date and respective dates and get the max value.

This can be achieved by doing `groupBy('company_master_id', 'as_on_date')` and calculating `max(delay_days)` and join all the 3 delay values(`max_delay_in_last_90_days`, `max_delay_in_last_180_days`, `max_delay_in_last_365_days`) by using 2 joins. But this is very slow. Instead I wanted to use window functions and `rangeBetween`.

I have tried this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as _max
tax_period_ts = unix_timestamp(col('t_tax_period'))
as_on_date_ts = unix_timestamp(col('as_on_date'))
days_90_before_u_ts = unix_timestamp(col('days_90_before'))

window_for_max = Window.partitionBy('company_master_id', 'as_on_date').orderBy(tax_period_ts.desc())\
                 .rangeBetween(as_on_date_ts, days_90_before_u_ts)

gst_delay_f = gst_delay_f.withColumn('90_days_max_value', _max('delay_days').over(window_for_max))
```

And it is not working and giving error saying it cannot convert column to bool. So how can i achieve this without using group by and then joining?

Comment: have you tried using `col('t_tax_period_u_ts')` ?

Comment: with the groupBy method, I don't think u would need the joins. wouldn't `F.max(F.when(col('t_tax_period').between(col('days_90_before'), col('as_on_date')), col('delay_days')).alias('max_90days')` work? You can write the 3 aggregations like this within the same groupby-aggregation context.

Comment: @ksgj1 this is what I tried.

`**
result = df.groupBy("company_master_id", "as_on_date").agg(
    when(df["t_tax_period"].between(df['as_on_date'], df['days_90_before']), _max("delay_days")).alias("max_delay_90_days_before")
)

result.show()
**`

this gives error because `t_tax_period` is not in group by clause

Comment: First, the first argument in between() should be the lower value. Second, the comment by @ksgj1 uses when() inside max() but you used max() inside when()